# Check if anywhere in the code a non-existent property is requested

Tags: javascript, typescript, static-analysis, jslint

I have a set of constants, looking like

```
let codes = {
    OPEN_ACCOUNT: 1000,
    CLOSE_ACCOUNT: 1001,
    DEPOSIT_FUNDS: 3000
    ...
}
```

Sometimes the keys are renamed, or added, or removed, so the structure of the `codes` object changes. As the app is quite large, I would be happy to statically analyze the code with some tool like JSLint/TSLint for cases when functions run with the code that is not available anymore:

```
runServerRequest(codes.DEPOSIT_FUNDS_SPECIAL_CASE, 500)
```

In the example above `DEPOSIT_FUNDS_SPECIAL_CASE` is not present in the codes object so it would be great to have a warning from the analyzer. In all possible cases, there shouldn't be cases when a non-existent field is requested.

How do I tackle this task the simplest way?

Comment: The issue is that codes object is generated automatically by server team guys and is pushed to the repo.

Comment: If you're using typescript then the compiler should complain about it, [like here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20codes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09OPEN_ACCOUNT%3A%201000%2C%0A%09%09CLOSE_ACCOUNT%3A%201001%2C%0A%09%09DEPOSIT_FUNDS%3A%203000%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09console.log(codes.OPEN_ACCOUNTS)%3B)

Comment: Yes, the app is in the middle of migration to TypeScript so codebase is a mix of JS+TS now, probably it will be fixed when all the code is in TypeScript.

Comment: You can also use the [facebook flow](https://flowtype.org) project, it's a "static type checker" for javascript. So you can use that for your js code. I haven't used it (as I'm using typescript) but maybe it can detect the errors in your case as well.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to set up a [`Proxy` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) that will throw if you access a non-existent property:

```
// define codes above this line.
codes = new Proxy(codes, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    if (!target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      throw new Error('Attempting to use the deleted code `' + prop + '`.');
    }
    return target[prop]
  }
});
```

The [`get` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) will trap all accesses to `code.some_property` and throw if it isn’t defined.
Note that this **will not** throw if the property has been explicitly set to `undefined`.

[Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy)

Comment: He's looking for a static analysis solution, it won't really help to find out about those at runtime (in production for example)

Comment: I am looking for a static way to analyze this issue. as Nitzan said.

Comment: @Sergei Yeah. I figured I’d leave it here in case someone can use it in the future.